# error c1083 canot find DbManager.h header file or No such directory

Tags: c++

Hi i am using visual studio 2008. i got the following error when trying to connect with oracle
error c1083 canot find DbManager.h heade file or No such directory.
below is the code that i have written.
     // Connection to DataBase.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define WIN32COMMON 
#include"DbManager.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std; 

class DataBaseConnectionTest
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        const string sqlstring("select * from info ");
        try
        { 
            cout<<"Hello"<<'\n';
            DbManager *db=new DbManager(system);
            OracleServices *os=db->getoracleServices();
            Connection *conn=os->connection();
            Statement *st=conn->createStatement(sqlstring);
            ResultSet *rs=st->executeQuery();
            string name;
            while(rs->next())
            {
                name=rs->getString(1);
                cout<<name<<" "<<'\n';
            }
            st->closeResultSet(rs);
            conn->terminateStatement(st);
        }
        catch(SQLException& se)
        {
            cout<<"Error Occured"<<"\n";
        }

    }
};

void main()
{
    DataBaseConnectionTest *dbc=new DataBaseConnectionTest();
    dbc->test();
}
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: How are you compiling your application ? Have you included the directory that contains the header file in the compiler's search path ?

Comment: I actually dont know where this header file resides! i have included the path of the directory where my occi header files are present buth in that folder  no DbManager.h haedr file is present. I googled for it also but did'nt got any hint. if you know then plse help me !

Answer (score 2):

Find the DbManager.h on disk. It's probably somewhere deep in the folder where the Oracle client is. Then add that folder to the project properties as the additional include folder. Project properties/Configuration properties/C.C++/General, add the folder with DbManager.h to the Additional Include directories.

You'll probably need to provide similar treatment for the static library file where the Oracle client stuff is. That's in the same window, under Linker.

Comment: There is no DbManager.h file available in my system ! can any body tell me where i can get these file ! do i need to download some libraries.