# DbManager.h not found

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio 2008 and want to connect my database to an oracle database. But while running the below code I'm getting following errors. Can anybody please help. I'm posting my code below.

```
// Connection to DataBase.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include"DbManager.h"
#define WIN32COMMON

#include<iostream>
#include <occi.h>
using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std; 


class DataBaseConnectionTest
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        const string sqlstring("select * from info ");
        try
        {
            cout<<"Hello"<<'\n';
            DbManager *db=new DbManager(system);
            OracleServices *os=db->getoracleServices();

            Connection *conn=os->connection();
            Statement *st=conn->createStatement(sqlstring);
            ResultSet *rs=st->executeQuery();
            string name;
            while(rs->next())
            {
                 name=rs->getString(1);
                 cout<<name<<" "<<'\n';
            }
            st->closeResultSet(rs);
            conn->terminateStatement(st);
        }
        catch(SQLException& se)
        {
            cout<<"Error Occured"<<"\n";
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    DataBaseConnectionTest *dbc=new DataBaseConnectionTest();
    dbc->test();
}
```

The errors are as given below:

> Error 1   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'DbManager.h': No such file or directory

I searched for the file but have not been able to find it.

Comment: Then that explains the error. You need to have the header file on your computer. You'll probably find it where you got this code from.

Comment: thank you for your response but i created this code by using books.  and they does'nt provide any header files. I googled alot but did'nt got any solution.and i searched every folder of oracle client present in my system on this path "E:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1" but there is no DbManager.h header file. If you know how to get these files then please post the path here. I will be very much thankful of you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error c1083 canot find DbManager.h heade file or No such directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349865/error-c1083-canot-find-dbmanager-h-heade-file-or-no-such-directory)

Comment: What is your Oracle home? `%ORACLE_HOME%` There must be an include folder inside that heirachy containing it(probably named oci)...

Comment: yes there is one folder name as (OCI) but in that folder there is no DbManager.h and Oracle Services header files. my oracle home environment variable is "E:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1" and Path environment variable is  "%ORACLE_HOME%\OCI\include;E:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;F:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;F:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin"

Comment: I have include the path of occi dlls in the "projecsettings->configurations->linker->Genaral->Addtional Library directories"  as "E:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1\OCI\lib\MSVC" there are two folders in this directory VC8 and VC7 and also some dlls and lib files. and inside these two folders there are Occi dlls and .lib are available. i have also included the path for the Occi.h header file in project settings->configuration->c/C++->General->Additional include directories as"E:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1\OCI\include". in this directory all the header files are available required for occi.h.

Comment: but still there are no DB Manager.h and Oracle Services header files are present

. Please help me and let me know wherei am lacking. i am trying with many different ways but not able to solve this problem. Do i need to download these two header files from somewhere else or i need to download the OCI library once again! because  i searched the whole system to find these two header files but did not got them. Is there any specific path where they resides if yes then please tell me.

Comment: can anybody tell me how to get these files in my program